# Compare 2 Cells and Find Missing Values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm currently comparing 2 databases where ZIP codes have been entered manually. I need to compare the ZIP codes for hundreds of accounts in each database to check if anything is missing. I've ordered all the values in ascending order in excel but cant seem to find a quick way to check what's missing.

```
Column A: Database A ZIPS (The correct ZIPs)
14464, 14515, 14612, 14615, 14626

Column B: Database B ZIPS (Manually Entered)
14464, 14612, 14615, 14626

Column C: Missing ZIPs
14515
```

EDIT: I should have clarified, the data is stored in this manner.. each zip is not stored in a separate column, there are multiple Zips for each agent.

[Image of worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrvdk.png)

I know there must be a way to find this value using an excel VBA!

Thanks

Comment: this will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx

Comment: @pnuts one is Microsoft CRM, and the other location is a google cloud storage service that needs to be modified after download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a go

`Public Function ShowMissingZips(rngSource As Range, _
                                rngMatch As Range) As String
    Dim colSource   As Collection
    Dim colMatch    As Collection
    Dim colOutput   As Collection
    Dim varSource   As Variant
    Dim varMatch    As Variant
    Dim varOutput   As Variant
    Dim intCounter  As Integer
    Dim blnMatched  As Boolean
    Dim strSource   As String
    Dim strMatch    As String
    Dim strOutput   As String`

```
Set colSource = New Collection
Set colMatch = New Collection
Set colOutput = New Collection

strSource = Replace(rngSource.Value, " ", "")
For Each varSource In Split(strSource, ",")
    colSource.Add varSource
Next

' Clean up source data
strMatch = Replace(rngMatch.Value, " ", "")
For Each varSource In Split(strMatch, ",")
    colMatch.Add varSource
Next

' Clean up match data    
For Each varSource In colSource
    blnMatched = False
    For Each varMatch In colMatch
        If varSource = varMatch Then
            blnMatched = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Note if it's not matched
    If Not blnMatched Then
        colOutput.Add varSource
    End If
Next

' Only output if there's anything present
If colOutput.Count > 0 Then
    For Each varOutput In colOutput
        strOutput = strOutput & CStr(varOutput) & ", "
    Next

    strOutput = Left$(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 2)
End If

ShowMissingZips = strOutput
```

End Function

To use it, press Alt-F11 to get to the VBA editor.  Find your workbook in the project explorer (Ctrl-R if not visible) and on the menu at the top click Insert..., Module.

Paste this code in.

Go back to your workbook and assuming that you've kept the columns as before (A, B & C and with row 2 as the first data row), go to cell C2 and type

`=ShowMissingZips(A2,B2)`

You should see what you're after.  It's not pretty and I'd normally add error handling, but it'll do for a quick fix.

When you save it, be sure to use the XLSM format (Excel 2007+) so that the VBA is retained.

Comment: Worked perfect!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer prior to seeing author's data format**
Luckily the task is not too hard. You just need to simply use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(list,value),"Output if it exists","Output if missing")
```

So in your case using the columns you define...

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A1),"",A1)
```

Then apply the formula for the length of the correct zip column.

see: https://exceljet.net/formula/find-missing-values

[Example picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLZly.png)

Comment: I should clarify, all the values are included in the same cell. So All the zips in column A are in A1, and all the zips in column B are in B1

Comment: You can go to Data->Text to Columns -> delimited -> csv
Then apply the formula

Comment: I understand this would work but I'm looking for a VBA to save time. Doing text to columns for this task would create hundreds of columns per agent and create an impossible environment to compare values

Comment: See added image for clarification

Comment: Ah. In that case I can't help you with Excel. Depending on the how the file itself is stored and the data structured it might just be easier to write a simple script in Python, R, MATLAB or another language that you're familiar with. If I were in your situation that is what I would do. Good luck